# AWS Lambda "Lambda can't find the file lambda_function.py. Make sure that your handler upholds the format: file-name.method." error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables

I am getting "Lambda can't find the file lambda_function.py. Make sure that your handler upholds the format: file-name.method." error just above the AWS Lambda function code block.
[You can see the warning here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/antJx.png)

But as you can see in this code block, my file name is lambda_function and my function name is lambda_handler.

```
import boto3
import os
import logging
import uuid
from webdriver_screenshot import WebDriverScreenshot

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('## ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES')
    logger.info(os.environ)
 
    screenshot_file = "{}-{}".format(''.join(filter(str.isalpha, os.environ['URL'])), str(uuid.uuid4()))
    driver = WebDriverScreenshot()

    logger.info('Generate fixed height screenshot')
    driver.save_screenshot(os.environ['URL'], '/tmp/{}-fixed.png'.format(screenshot_file), height=1024)

    logger.info('Generate full height screenshot')    
    driver.save_screenshot(os.environ['URL'], '/tmp/{}-full.png'.format(screenshot_file))

    driver.close()

    if all (k in os.environ for k in ('BUCKET','DESTPATH')):
        ## Upload generated screenshot files to S3 bucket.
        s3.upload_file('/tmp/{}-fixed.png'.format(screenshot_file), 
                    os.environ['BUCKET'], 
                    '{}/{}-fixed.png'.format(os.environ['DESTPATH'], screenshot_file))
        s3.upload_file('/tmp/{}-full.png'.format(screenshot_file), 
                    os.environ['BUCKET'], 
                    '{}/{}-full.png'.format(os.environ['DESTPATH'], screenshot_file))
```

My code folder is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCPsc.png) and the main python code is in [src folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTcfE.png). In AWS Lambda, my folder is looking [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyWse.png). I do not understand what is the problem.

Even worse, when I try to test the code in AWS Lambda environment, [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/finhN.png) is showing up. It says:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'boto3'

But I have the boto3 module [in the layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xbld.png), it is uploaded from my S3 Bucket. It is succesfully  [added to the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V71QU.png)

The only thing I am suspecting, I may wrote environment variables wrong as shown here: [environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HdtW.png) due to I am a beginner in coding and AWS Lambda, I just copied both the PATH and PYTHONPATH from somewhere.

I don't know what to do next and need some support here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem when I tried to use an external module in lambda_function, in my case was OpenCV as lambda layer. For making Opencv to work I have to change environment variables, making the key `PYTHONPATH` to have the value `/opt/` as is describe it in this [tutorial](https://itnext.io/create-a-highly-scalable-image-processing-service-on-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-in-10-minutes-7cbb2893a479). Then I have the same problem you describe `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'boto3'`, what is kind of strange as boto3 suppose to be integrate in the path of lambda. In my understanding, is just a conflict with the directories.

The way it solves for me was changing the value of the environment variables from `/opt/` to `/opt:/var/runtime`. Hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

No worries, I can help you with this. For the first `Lambda can't find the file lambda_function.py` issue, try prepending `src/` to the handler value in the function configuration since your Python scripts are not located in the top-level directory. For the second issue related to lambda layers, it's true that you messed up the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. If you are using layers, you don't need to overwrite this variable. Just leave it unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I really appreaciate that. I removed the edited environment variables. Wrote as I found in the first place "PATH: /var/task/bin" and "PYTHONPATH: /var/task/src:/var/task/lib". For the first part, should I write, "src/lambda_function.lambda_handler" in the runtime settings or do I have to add that in the different place? Sorry if I am asking stupid questions, I am very beginner at this. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you should enter `src/lambda_function.lambda_handler` @bilalsedef

Comment: I did as you suggested, now I have another error. `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'src/lambda_function'"` `Unable to import module 'src/lambda_function': No module named 'boto3'`

Comment: Try printing out `PYTHONPATH` in the code and see if it gets overwritten.

Comment: No change, still getting the boto3 error. Even if I comment boto3 lines out.

Comment: You can locate the line that caused this error in the error trace.

Comment: Sorry, I am little lost atm. I didn't get where do you want me to print out `PYTHONPATH`, in AWS or in my local environment? I don't know how to do that in either way.

Comment: Please join us in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214788/aws-chat), so we can continue the discussion.